# Access files on Linux

Tags: linux, hadoop

Use remote tools mtputty to access the Linux on the virtual machine. The file is present. It always shows No Such Directory or File.I don't know why.

[image: picture show the file exists but can't access]

I hope you can help me with this problem. It has been bothering me for a long time.

Comment: try to run command in terminal to show files `ls -la /data/input/`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.